# iterator was not set on data decoded from API

Tags: list, flutter, dart, iterator

so I'm at lost of why this happened. I keep receiving error in console log that says `The getter 'iterator' was called on null` .

What I'm sure of:

1. I know this is not the case because the data returned from api is there.
2. The decoded data is also there.
3. And the view renders the data perfectly fine, so the data is obviously there.

But the error keeps on popping it's like, the decoded data decoded
    from JSON turned to map then list is missing of iterator attribute.
    Can someone help me on this ?

This is the code and the error showed by dart debugger.Thanks.

[image: Weird Error]

Here is the `response.body` of the api call. So yeah the data is there. Sorry about the red highlight since i can't show you the content.

[image]

Comment: Could you share result of `json.decode(response.body)` and in particular `json.decode(response.body)['data']`?

Comment: Indeed can you post the respone body?

Comment: @Oshibka404 i've added the result of json.decode(response.body) to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the request initialization to
`List<Dynamic> request = new List() ;`
And remove the cast `as List<dynamic >;`